# How to add user input into a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get get user input, which is stored in an array (eightBit[]), and then add that to a 2D array (board).  The user is supposed to enter 8 numbers, for an example:
Byte 1: 1
Byte 2: 2
etc...
and the output is supposed to look like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

however this is the output I get:

```
8 8 8 8
8 8 8 8
```

Any idea why its repeating only the last numbered entered?  Part of my code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
cout << "Enter a pattern of eight bits:" << endl;
            for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                cout << "Byte " << i+1 << ": ";
                cin >> eightBit[i];
            }

int board[2][4];

            for(i = 0; i<8; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
                for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    board[j][k] = eightBit[i];

                }
            }

            for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0; k<4; k++) 
                {
                    cout << board[j][k]  << "  ";
                }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: The pairs of `{` and `}` around your `for` loops where you copy from `eightBit` into `board` don't add up -- and they might be crucial to your problem. Can you try to post compilable code?

Answer (score 2):

That's because of your outer loop with `i` which is basically overwriting every element in your 2D array.

A solution would be to drop that outer loop entirely, like so:

```
int i = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
            board[j][k] = eightBit[i++];
        }
    }
```

also you have **bracket mismatch** in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

That's natural. In the second for when the i gets at last 8, then the board gets filled with the current i (i=8).
Try this, and next time be more careful with your code :).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int eightBit[2][4];

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a pattern of eight bits:" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i <2; i++){
            for (int j=0 ; j<4 ; ++j)  {
                cout << "Byte " << (j+1)+4*i << ": ";    //4 = # of columns,i=row,j=column.
                cin >> eightBit[i][j];
            }
        }


    int board[2][4];


    for(int i = 0; i <2; i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<4 ; ++j)  {
            board[i][j] = eightBit[i][j];

        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <2; i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<4 ; ++j)  {

            cout << board[i][j]  << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
   }

}
```

Comment: linear index = row * numCols + col